# How does the machinery of left-exact comonads generalize from sheaves to stacks?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, stacks, sheaf-theory

Suppose that we have two Grothendieck sites, their associated sheaves $\mathcal{E}=\rm{Sh}(\bf{C},J)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\rm{Sh}(\bf{D},K)$ and a geometric surjection $f:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{F}$. This is completely determined by a faithful, left-exact, cover-preserving functor $f_0:\bf{D}\to \mathcal{E}$, which induces the inverse image $f^*$ by left Kan extension.

We should be able to play the same game for stacks. Any stack $G$ over $(\bf{D},K)$ has a presentation as a (pseudo)colimit of representables: $G\simeq\varinjlim_i yD_i$ and we set $f^*G\simeq\varinjlim_i f(D_i)$. Does this induce a "2-geometric morphism" $\rm{Stacks}(\bf{C},J)\to\rm{Stacks}(\bf{D},K)$. In what sense, if any, is this morphism a "2-surjection"?

In the case of sheaves, the geometric morphism induces a left-exact comonad on $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the category of coalgebras for this comonad. Is there an analogous statement for stacks?

Comment: I'll try to come back and answer this later when I have more time (it's late here), but for now: since you get a morphism between the toposes of sheaves on the two sites, you get a morphism between their 2-toposes of stacks, since there is a full and faithful embedding of the bicategory of toposes into the the tricategory of 2-toposes.

Comment: @DavidCarchedi This is an interesting question and you are welcomed to post an answer if you are available now :)

Comment: It's true for stacks fibred in groupoids a fortiori from the results in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory (there are probably easier proofs though).  For stacks fibred in ordinary categories, I can't seem to find anything.  Probably the right way to do it is to first try it for pseudopresheaves of categories, as a sort of 2-Yoneda lemma. It should follow from that.

Comment: One particular especially simple and especially interesting case: suppose $\mathcal E$ has enough points, so there is a surjection from $\mathbf{Set}/\operatorname{pt}(\mathcal E)$ to $\mathcal E$. Then, $\mathcal E$ is equivalent to the category of coalgebras over (or under?) a Cartesian comonad on a slice of $\mathbf{Set}$. What would be analog of this for stacks?